# Though two values are equal returns false

Tags: javascript

```
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    //console.log(this) //{}
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;

       // console.log(this) //{ name: 'Captain Cook', numLegs: 2 }
      //console.log(penguin) //{ name: 'Captain Cook', numLegs: 2 }
     //console.log(typeof(this)) //object
    //console.log(typeof(penguin)) //object
   //console.log(this===penguin)//flase
    console.log(this==penguin);//flase

 }



// create the sayName method for Animal


Animal.prototype.sayName = function () {
    //console.log("Hi my name is"+ " " + this.name);
   //console.log(this) //{ name: 'Captain Cook', numLegs: 2 }
  //console.log(this===penguin) //true
};

// provided code to test above constructor and method
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

...............................................................................................................................................................
why `this==penguin` false even though two values are equal ?please elaborate it
...............................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

The only un-commented-out `console.log(this === penguin);` line in that code is executed **before** `penguin` is set to the result of calling `Answer` via `new`. So `penguin` is `undefined`, and of course, the new object is not `=== undefined`.

Consider this simpler example showing the value of `penguin`:

```js
function Animal() {
    console.log("first", typeof penguin); // undefined
}
var penguin = new Animal();
console.log("second", typeof penguin);    // object
```

Whereas one of the later commented-out `console.log(this === penguin);` lines in your code *would* show true: The one used *after* the `new Animal` expression has been completed and the result assigned to `penguin`:

```js
function Animal() {
    console.log("first", typeof penguin);    // undefined
}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("third", typeof penguin);    // object
    console.log("equal?", this === penguin); // true
};
var penguin = new Animal();
console.log("second", typeof penguin);       // object
penguin.sayName();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the way equality is checked for primitive values such as strings and integers is same as it is in any other language. But JavaScript objects are considered equal only if the references of these objects are the same. (If both are referring to the same object.) Even if all attributes are the same if they are two different objects they are not considered as equal.

You are checking the equality of the prototype constructor and the object created using the constructor. The references to these two objects are not equal although the attributes are same. Therefore you get false.

Answer (score -1):

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html explains that objects in javascript are compared by reference. In that sense, `this` and `penguin` may be *equivalent*, but they're not *equal*.